# recursive update tensor with out loop in session

Tags: python, tensorflow

It is necessary to update the tensor without saving it to the python.

I want get :

```
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([4.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([16.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([65536.], dtype=float32)]
```

But I get:

```
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
[array([2.], dtype=float32), array([2.], dtype=float32)]
```

my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])
def ret(x, y):
    return x, tf.pow(x, y)
try:
    x, y = ret(inp,y)
except:
    x, y = ret(inp, tf.Variable([1.]))

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(4):
    print (sess.run([x,y],{inp: [2.]}))
```

Sorry, incorrectly described my problem.
in fact, the code for the ret function is slightly different.

```
def ret(inputs, compare_vectors=tf.Variable([])):
    boxes = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,4)).astype(np.float32))
    box_ind = tf.Variable(np.zeros([10],dtype=np.int))
    crop_size= tf.Variable([24,24])
    crop_boxes = tf.image.crop_and_resize(inputs, boxes, box_ind, crop_size)
    crop_boxes = tf.reshape(crop_boxes,[crop_boxes.get_shape().as_list()[0], 24,24,3])
    with slim.arg_scope(get_futures_maps_arg_scope()):
        future_maps, _ = get_futures_maps(crop_boxes, is_training = False)
    rows = tf.unstack(compare_vectors) 
    column = tf.unstack(future_maps) 
    result = tf.ones(shape=[len(rows), len(column)])
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        for j, future in enumerate(column):
            result[i,j]=tf.losses.cosine_distance(row, future)
    compare_vectors = future_maps

    return crop_boxes, boxes, future_maps, result
```

the main problem is that the result looks like [] always, but I need [10,10] in second, third and fours steps

main function:

```
compare_vectors = None
if compare_vectors is None:
    crop_boxes, boxes, compare_vectors, result = ret(inputs)
else:
    crop_boxes, boxes, compare_vectors, result = ret(inputs, compare_vectors)
```

i change code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[10, 10])
test_shape_var = tf.Variable(np.ones([0,10], dtype=np.float32))
def ret(x, y):
    len_var = tf.fill([len(tf.unstack(y))], -1)
    return len_var
x = inp-1.
test_len_var = ret(x, test_shape_var)
update_shape_var = tf.assign(test_shape_var, x, validate_shape=False)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(10):
    x_, y_ = sess.run([test_len_var,test_shape_var],{inp: np.random.uniform(0,1, [10, 10])})
    sess.run(update_shape_var, {inp: np.random.uniform(0,1, [10, 10])})
    print (x_.shape, y_.shape)
```

But I dont know why not updated vars in function "ret"

Last code calculate twice tensor x.

In original code need updated matrix size "result"

sorry for my english - this is not my native language

Comment: `tf.assign()` returns a tensor!!! By doing this you lose a reference to a variable. It should rather be `assign_op = tf.assign(my_var, some_new_values)` and then you execute it as `sess.run(assign_op)`.

Comment: Describe what do you want to achieve with `ret` function, or what do you expect your code to do. Also, it is better if you could provide input example and the corresponding output example of transformation you're trying to implement. Otherwise, it is difficult to help.